# .NET Core MySql TypeLoadException - Method Clone

Tags: mysql, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to make a .NET Core 2.0 console application work with a MySQL database using Entity Framework.

I've tried both the Oracle ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore/ ) and Pomelo ( https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql ) connectors and both of them throw a TypeLoadException:

Oracle Exception:

```
System.TypeLoadException occurred
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Method 'Clone' in type 'MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.Internal.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=8.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d' does not have an implementation.
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
   at MySQL.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions.MySQLDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySQL(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 MySQLOptionsAction)
   at Common.DAL.MyContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in Program.cs:line 18
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
...
```

Pomelo Exception:

```
{System.TypeLoadException: Method 'Clone' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.MySqlOptionsExtension' from assembly 'Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.MySqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseMySql
   at Common.DAL.MyContext.OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) in Program.cs:line 18
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
...
```

Comment: [EF Core 2.0 requires a 2.0 database provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/1x-2x-upgrade#ef-core-2.0-requires-a-2.0-database-provider) and looks like none of the MySQL providers has been upgraded to 2.0 yet. Pomelo 2.0.0 [release schedule](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#schedule-and-roadmap) is September 4th, 2017, may be you could try the [prerelease build](https://www.myget.org/Package/Details/pomelo?packageType=nuget&packageId=Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql) or wait a few more days.

Comment: thanks, prerelease build works